# iOS Drag & Drop With 2 Different Views

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop

I need to create drag and drop with 2 UIScrollViews. 
The First level of DAD-"Drag and Drop" is DAD inside first UIScrollView.
And the second DAD is DAD between 2 different UIScrollViews. 
Moving needed element from list of my elements to other list. 
Like this:
[Example here](http://www.guidedways.com/mobile/groups/)

Is there standart API for this things or I have to create it by myself?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, I think you'll have to make your own. As an example, you can look at my [github](https://github.com/aakash272/dragDrop) repo. It's not as neat and elegant looking as **groups** but it accomplishes the functionality you desire. I've used table-views which are basically scroll-views.